# How to attach/upload a file to node using restws?

Tags: services, files, 8

I've got a content type with "File" field and "File" widget. I am **successfully** able to create a node **without** a file using **restws**. But, if I want to attach a file to it, it just doesn't allow me to do that. I've tried many different things, but with failure.

Also, when accessing a node with file already attached to it, using get request (e.g. {domain_name}/node/219.json), the file field is displayed as an empty element, even though file is existing and is displayed fine when viewing the node in edit mode from admin area.

E.g.

JSON:

```
"field_simple_file":[]
```

XML:

```
<field_simple_file/>
```

The node array without file field, that succeeds is as below:

```
$new_node = array(
    'body' => array(),
    'type' => 'simple',
    'title' => 'Content created with restws',
    'language' => 'und',
    'status' => 1,
    'promote' => 0,
    'sticky' => 0,
    'author' => 1    
);
```

And content-type:

```
'Content-Type: application/json'
```

But I think, I am not 100% sure on how to include a file in it (have tried few different things), which might be leading to failure. Can anyone provide me with guidance for attaching/uploading a file with restws please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the URL to access a node with file already attached to it

`{domain_name}/[end-point]/node/219.json`

Here 219 is the nid of the node.

Here is the sample JSON format to attach a file to node (node create).

```
{
    "title": "title_of_node",
    "type": "bundle_name",
    "field_samplefile": {
        "und": [{
            "fid": "17",
            "filename": "changes.txt",
            "uri": "public://changes.txt",
            "filemime": "text/plain"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created (and I am maintaining) the [RESTful web services support for files and images](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws_file) module, which I believe does exactly what you were asking for.

> This module provides support for creating and updating fields of type file and
>   image. It accepts (multiple) image/file data as base64_encoded strings in the
>   JSON payload.

It requires the [RESTful Web Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws) module.